# Rails—how to drop a specific database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rake db:drop` destroys everything, but I only want to drop specific db's.

I tried a parallel testing gem which created these databases: `my_db_test2, my_db_test3, my_db_test4`

How do I delete only those databases?

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop` will drop all test databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Postgres, you can use [`dropdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropdb.html):

```
dropdb my_db_test2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify environment while destroying databases.

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
```

Note: By default `rake db:drop` will drop all databases associated with the application.

Comment: As of Rails 7.0.4, `bin/rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=development` still drops, whereas `bin/rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test` only drops test.